# Cast datatype from array to String for multiple column in Spark Throwing Error

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataframe df that contains Three column of type array, i am trying to save output
to csv, so converted data type to string.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
 val df2 = df.withColumn("Total", col("total").cast("string")),
      ("BOOKID", col("BOOKID").cast("string"),
      "PublisherID", col("PublisherID").cast("string")
      .write
      .csv(path="D:/pennymac/SOLUTION1/OUTPUT")
```

But getting error.

```
error as "Cannot Resolve symbol write"
```

Spark 2.2
Scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

Its not possible to add multiple columns inside `withColumn` function.

```
val df2 = df
      .withColumn("Total", col("total").cast("string"))
      .withColumn("BOOKID", col("BOOKID").cast("string"))
      .withColumn("PublisherID", col("PublisherID").cast("string"))
      .write
      .csv(path="D:/pennymac/SOLUTION1/OUTPUT")
```